# onActivityResult not called across applications

Tags: android, android-intent

I've read several SO posts for similar problems, but unfortunately none of the solutions proposed seem to apply to me.  I have two applications communicating with each other.  In one case, an Activity from app A needs to be started from an Activity in app B, perform a task, then return just a success code to app B.

So in app B, I use `startActivityForResult` like this:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent();
startIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.mydomain.appA", "com.mydomain.appA.MainActivity"));
startIntent.setAction("com.mydomain.intent.action.DO_STUFF");
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("important info", "info");
startIntent.putExtras(extras);
try {
    startActivityForResult(startIntent, 1002);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I do *not* call `finish()` in app B after doing this (this seems to be a common problem here, but it isn't mine).  I also saw some issues reported when using request codes less than 1, but my request code is 1002 so this shouldn't be an issue either.

And here is my manifest entry for the Activity in app B, just the default MainActivity from Android Studio (I read some things about Activity settings in the manifest causing issues, but I can't imagine the default settings would not work):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In MainActivity in app A, I handle the incoming Intent:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action != null  && action.equals("com.mydomain.intent.action.DO_STUFF")){
       boolean success;  //this gets updated as we carry out the request
       //Do stuff
       //... More Code ...
       if(success){
         setResult(RESULT_OK);
       }
       else {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
       }
       finish();
    }
}
```

At this point everything is golden: app A gets the Intent from app B, carries out the request, finishes, and then MainActivity from app B is on the screen again, but for some reason this code never gets run:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a result");
    if(requestCode == 1002){
        if(resultCode != RESULT_OK){
            Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong or user cancelled");
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "All good!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unknown response");
    }
}
```

If I use `startActivityForResult` to start another Activity within app B, everything works fine and `onActivityResult` gets called.  When using it to start MainActivity from app A, though, I just wind up in `onResume` of app B after it finishes, so I have no indication of success or failure.

I am more than happy to give more details if they might be relevant, unfortunately my actual app code is pretty elaborate so I just posted a very simplified version here.

Comment: "In MainActivity in app A, I handle the incoming Intent" -- why are you using an `Activity` here? The point behind an activity is usually to show a UI to the user. If all you are doing is IPC, why not use something else that is more purely IPC? Broadcasts, services, and content providers all also provide IPC. "If I use startActivityForResult to start another Activity within app B, everything works fine and onActivityResult gets called" -- are any of those activities ones like the one you show here, where you are trying to call `setResult()` and `finish()` right in `onCreate()`?

Comment: There actually is some UI going on here, I just abstracted it for the sake of keeping the post simple.  In reality there are actually several function calls being made from onCreate, and finish() is not actually called from onCreate, it gets called after the user makes some UI selections.  I could just use startActivity and then broadcast a result, but startActivityForResult has the lovely benefit of allowing you to get the signature of the calling package.  I really need the security here.

Comment: Well, `startActivityForResult()` certainly works across applications, as can be seen in countless examples using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, `ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and so on. So it is not that `startActivityForResult()` is somehow generally broken across app boundaries.

Comment: @CommonsWare I completely agree. I even have a few applications of my own which do this just fine.  I'm just banging my head against a wall trying to figure out what I did wrong here: I know the issue is certainly with my code, but I can't find any detailed explanations online of the edge cases where `startActivityForResult` would fail.  For example, you mentioned a possibility that calling `setResult` and `finish` in onCreate might be causing the issue, but I had never seen that mentioned anywhere (thanks for the suggestion by the way).

Comment: "you mentioned a possibility that calling setResult and finish in onCreate might be causing the issue" -- that was just a guess, as it would be an unusual scenario. I have no idea if that works or doesn't. Out of curiosity, check your process IDs. Is the process that called `startActivityForResult()` the same process that gets control back (minus `onActivityResult()`) after you call `setResult()` and `finish()`? Or was your first app's process terminated while the second app was in the foreground, then restarted?

Comment: Looks like the process ID is the same.  I had a similar thought before and logged when onDestroy was called, but I never thought to check the ID as well. The pid returned by `android.os.Process.myPid()` is the same before and after the call, so my app is definitely running the whole time.

Comment: AFAIK, under the covers, `startActivityForResult()` uses `createPendingResult()`, ships that `PendingIntent` over to the started activity, which then triggers it when you call `setResult()`. That should be using a dynamic `BroadcastReceiver`, and I don't know what would be interfering with that. You might try having your first activity call `startActivityForResult()` on something else (e.g., pick a contact). If you don't get a response there, the problem presumably lies in your first activity.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I'll check that out and see what I can find

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get this working on my end, though I can't claim to really understand why.  On the off chance that this helps someone else, I'll go ahead and post what I did:

After calling `setResult` and `finish` I added a `return`.  I wish I could add more information regarding why this helped, but I actually included that `return` to solve a separate issue and just happened to notice `onActivityResult` was being called.